# Code signing for linux executable using install4j

Tags: linux, install4j, code-signing-certificate

I am using Install4j and .pfx file in order to provide digital signature for my installer (.exe) for windows, but I can't find any way to do it for my installer for linux (.sh).
There are any way to do it using Install4j for linux executables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for signing on Linux/Unix. Code signing in install4j is only supported for Windows and macOS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ingo!
There is no other way?
For example using some script in install4j?

Comment: No, there is no such support. What kind of signing would you like to implement? The installers are shell scripts.